# Put in one field, values from other fields in one row with some extra text EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have situation like his

```
Text    Number    Letter     Color

empty     1         A         Blue
```

I want to put vales from Number, Letter and Color in Text field to look like this:

```
Text                Number       Letter     Color

Number is: 1          1            A         Blue
Letter is: A
Color is: Blue
```

How to put all this value from other fields with some extra text into one field in excel?

Comment: I don't see how this can't be done without simple A1, B1, C1, D1 references. Do you mean to ask, how can you create that form from one cell?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean

Comment: Are you looking into combining text and cell values in one cell? Something like this `="Number is: 1" & B1` , where `B3` = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
="Number is: " & B2 & char(10) & "Letter is: " & C2 & Char(10) & "Color is: " & D2
```

Make sure WrapText is enabled.

[image]

If you have TEXTJOIN then you can use this array:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,$B$1:$D$1 & " is: " & B2:D2)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel

[image]

---

To do in separate cells put this in the first cell:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,ROW(1:1)) & " is: " & INDEX($B$2:$D$2,,ROW(1:1))
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: @xTwisteDx and that is?

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Should give him the ability to use the data within that cell later on if he needs it instead of having it all limited to one cell.

Comment: @xTwisteDx to do it in separate cells one could do `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,ROW(1:1)) & " is: " & INDEX($B$2:$D$2,,ROW(1:1))` in the first cell and copy down.  Excel requires a formula in every cell that expects an output.

Comment: Yes i need this in more cells,i put this only like example.

Comment: @xTwisteDx you should ask before using my formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, coincidentally, I didn't use your formula. Check your values, yours is incorrect from what I've  been doing. I gave you your rep for + answer. I'm not one of those guys. Had I used yours it would return `Text is:` then `Number` then  `Letter`, not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: You only shifted the range, but it is basically my formula. @xTwisteDx

Comment: @xTwisteDx I am just saying that you at least should give me a shout out on your answer.

Comment: when i put this in a text, i want to delete other columns...can i do it?

Comment: will my text missing?

Comment: @doki that is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

## `Excel Method`

Use the formula `=INDEX($C$1:$E$1,,ROW(1:1)) & " is: " & INDEX($C$2:$E$2,,ROW(1:1))` INSIDE EACH Cell you want it to copy the data from.

[image]

## `GOOGLE SHEET METHOD`

You can use the formula: `={{"Number is: ", C2}; {"Letter is: ", D2}; {"Color is: ", E2}}` In any 1 cell. Giving you this.

[image]

Comment: That is google sheets not excel,  This will not work in excel.

Comment: No it does not.  There are many things that work in Excel that does not work in Google Sheets and vice verca